# git rebase -i commit flags?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When applying a squashed or reworded commit, `rebase -i` invokes the commit editor automatically. I'm used to committing with `commit -v` (I want to see what diff I'm committing), but the rebase-invoked `git commit` seems to not set `-v`. This is super-annoying when squashing commits.

Is there a way to configure the `git commit` flags for use inside the `rebase loop`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`git-commit(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--v):

> **-v**, **--verbose**
>
> Show unified diff between the HEAD commit and what would be committed at the bottom of the commit message template to help the user describe the commit by reminding what changes the commit has. Note that this diff output doesn’t have its lines prefixed with `#`. This diff will not be a part of the commit message. See the `commit.verbose` configuration variable in [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

This means the verbose mode can be permanently enabled globally by doing

```
git config --global commit.verbose true
```

This way, the `-v` option will be enabled by default from now on.

Alternatively, the option can be enabled on a per-command basis by passing the `-c` global option:

```
git -c commit.verbose=true rebase -i
```

Comment: Hm, I should probably `git config -g commit.verbose true`, and just use `--no-verbose` / `-c ..` if ever running into a huge patch